# How to import Python module in another folder, without relative import and editing PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, import, module

This is my folder structure:

```
.
├── main.py
├── formats
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── writer.py
└── misc
    ├── __init__.py
    └── util.py
```

In `main.py`, I can import `util.py` using:

```py
from misc.util import sth
```

However, I can't import `util.py` in `writer.py`, using the above statement, and this command:

```sh
python formats/writer.py
```

Now the simplest solution is to mess with the `PYTHONPATH`: a simple `export PYTHONPATH=.` will do it. However, I don't like doing so, and don't like relative import. What are my options now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The import mechanism is based on PYTHONPATH.

When you run `python main.py`, then the directory containing `main.py` is in PYTHONPATH, so all other packages there are importable as well.

When you run `python formats/writer.py`, then the `formats` directory is in PATHONPATH and its parent directory is not, so you cannot import modules and packages which are not in `formats`.

What you can do, is run `writer` module, but have the root directory in PATHONPATH and you can do that without even messing with environment variables:

```
cd /directory/in/which/main.py/is
python -m formats.writer
```

Unlike `python formats/writer.py`, which changes PYTHONPATH and runs `writer.py`, this keeps the default PYTHONPATH (current directory) and tells Python to look within that path for a module named `formats.writer` and run that as the main module.

Comment: Hi, I see a pattern here. Many tools that use `SOMETHINGPATH` use the parent folder of the desired file as `SOMETHINGPATH`, not the folder where it is run (`pwd`). Is it a preferred pattern, and what's the name of the pattern if it is?